# Cannot Parse through XML element due to no EOL between XML tags: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: java

I have the following situation: I am receiving a payload of XML elements with no root element or space/newLines between XML tags, example:

```
<4f>Content</4f><50>MoreContent</50><5f24>SomeMoreContent</5f24>
```

I am wondering what the best way of parsing the XML string so I can evaluate each tag inside the string.

Now, in my code I am adding a root element in order to parse the tag successful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><EMVData><4f>Content</4f><50>MoreContent</50><5f24>SomeMoreContent</5f24></EMVData>
```

The issue is when I attempt to create a Document, I get the following exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

Thus, I believe I need to add EOL characters between the XML tags I am receiving. I am just unsure as to what the best way around it. I would like assistance in parsing the XML string I am receiving.

here is my code snippet:

```
    try {
      String emvSource = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><EMVData>" + argEmvMessage +"</EMVData>";
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
      DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(emvSource.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

XML elements can't start with a digit.  You'll have to replace the digit element names with valid names in order to get the data to parse.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I have no control over the payload being provided. I will have to figure a different approach.